# Access Userform/VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

want to create a user form with 4 drop down(product name, month, year) and a number field demand. 
the monthly demand entered by the user should be divided by 4 to convert it to weekly data and stored in the table. I was able to achieve this in excel and i am unable to do so in access 2016. below is my excel vba code:

```
Private Sub CmdInsert_Click()

Dim eRow As Long
Dim a As Integer
 eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

 Select Case Cmonth.Value

Case "Jan": a = 5
While a > 0

Cells(eRow, 2).Value = Cdemand.Value / 5
Cells(eRow, 1).Value = Cproduct.Value
'Cells(eRow, 2).Value = Cdemand.Value
Cells(eRow, 3).Value = Cmonth.Value
Cells(eRow, 4).Value = Cyear.Value
Cells(eRow, 5).Value = a
Cells(eRow, 6).Value = Cells(eRow, 2).Value / 10000

eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
a = a - 1
Wend


Case "feb": a = 9
While a > 5

Cells(eRow, 2).Value = Cdemand.Value / 4
Cells(eRow, 1).Value = Cproduct.Value
'Cells(eRow, 2).Value = Cdemand.Value
Cells(eRow, 3).Value = Cmonth.Value
Cells(eRow, 4).Value = Cyear.Value
Cells(eRow, 5).Value = a
Cells(eRow, 6).Value = Cells(eRow, 2).Value / 10000
eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
a = a - 1
Wend

Case "Mar": a = 13
While a > 9

Cells(eRow, 2).Value = Cdemand.Value / 4
Cells(eRow, 1).Value = Cproduct.Value
'Cells(eRow, 2).Value = Cdemand.Value
Cells(eRow, 3).Value = Cmonth.Value
Cells(eRow, 4).Value = Cyear.Value
Cells(eRow, 5).Value = a
Cells(eRow, 6).Value = Cells(eRow, 2).Value / 10000
eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
a = a - 1
Wend

Case "Apr": a = 18
While a > 13

Cells(eRow, 2).Value = Cdemand.Value / 5
Cells(eRow, 1).Value = Cproduct.Value
'Cells(eRow, 2).Value = Cdemand.Value
Cells(eRow, 3).Value = Cmonth.Value
Cells(eRow, 4).Value = Cyear.Value
Cells(eRow, 5).Value = a
Cells(eRow, 6).Value = Cells(eRow, 2).Value / 10000
eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
a = a - 1
Wend

Case "May": a = 22
While a > 18

Cells(eRow, 2).Value = Cdemand.Value / 4
Cells(eRow, 1).Value = Cproduct.Value
'Cells(eRow, 2).Value = Cdemand.Value
Cells(eRow, 3).Value = Cmonth.Value
Cells(eRow, 4).Value = Cyear.Value
Cells(eRow, 5).Value = a
Cells(eRow, 6).Value = Cells(eRow, 2).Value / 10000
eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
a = a - 1
Wend


End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What if there are 5 weeks in the month? Your current code is hard coded to determine the weeks in a month, but the real calendar isn't. You would be better working out a daily run-rate based on the working days in any given month.

Comment: What exactly are you "unable to do" in Access? Yes, that code will not be helpful in Access, you'll need to modifiy it, is that the issue?

Comment: That said, I've no idea what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Access is much easier to create userform than excel. Goto Create -> Forms Design.
Add controls and in code behind you can achieve the same goal.

Also, the data can be inserted into an access table. Which makes the job easy to query and manipulate the data.

Comment: Create -> Forms Design is **NOT** a `MSForms.UserForm` object. These are *Access Forms*, which are document object modules (same as a `Worksheet` module in Excel, i.e. owned by the host application), with a designer that's part of Access, not the VBE. Creating a **UserForm** in Access is actually *more* complicated, since the Access-VBE *hides* the command. Please do not conflate Access Forms with MSForms UserForms. They are completely and wildly different techs.